# How to use youtube videos in the GUI with Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, youtube

I'm a beginner at Tkinter and would like to place YouTube videos like a button in a Tkinter window, so that when the user clicks on the video, he is taken to YouTube and watches, or to a screen with the video. If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: You can add web hyperlinks with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482748/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-with-a-label-in-tkinter), if that's what you want.

Comment: Adding to what @ObsoleteAwareProduce said, the best way is to do this is to use the `command` kwarg (on the `Button` widget)  to then make a call to the `webbrowser` library. Believe me when I say you do **not** what to try and embed the video in your application (though if you *really* want to try, take a look at the `youtube_dl` library and possibly combine it with `ffmpeg` for playback with no audio - combining audio is another problem altogether)